# Safe global variables in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

I have global variable in node.js named i and also have two different function using i++. After running the code, during first function increasing the i variable, is it get back in to event loop due to read-modify-write operation? If so can another function using i++ get the right value from the global variable (correctly increased)?

Comment: yes, there is no concurrency in JS on instruction level.

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't be using a global at all - that's just the wrong design.  Counters like this should be more locally scoped, either scoped to a function or to a module.